Segmentation fault while setting hiredis.hiredisAllocFuncs by je_malloc
I compile jemalloc with version v5.3.0 and execute configure-cmd with argment --with-jemalloc-prefix=jee_
In C script, set hiredisAllocFuncs as Follows:
    hiredisAllocFuncs myfuncs = {
        .mallocFn = jee_malloc,
        .callocFn = jee_calloc,
        .reallocFn = jee_realloc,
        .strdupFn = strdup,
        .freeFn = jee_free,
    };

    hiredisAllocFuncs orig = hiredisSetAllocators(&myfuncs);

while after gcc-lhiredis -lpthread -ljemalloc
and run it，I got Segmentation fault. more gdb info as follows:

(gdb) s


__pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=0x7ffffff9c7d0, attr=0x0, start_routine=0x555555554de9 <perform_redis_operation>, arg=0x7ffffff9c910) at pthread_create.c:610
610 pthread_create.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New Thread 0x7ffff65ff700 (LWP 24326)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5dfe700 (LWP 24327)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff55fd700 (LWP 24328)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff49ff700 (LWP 24329)]
[New Thread 0x7fffefbff700 (LWP 24330)]
Thread 2 "***-c" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff65ff700 (LWP 24326)]
tcache_bin_flush_impl (small=true, nflush=81, ptrs=0x7ffff65fe220, binind=, cache_bin=, tcache=, tsd=0x7ffff65fe270) at src/tcache.c:350
350 unsigned cur_arena_ind = edata_arena_ind_get(edata);
(gdb) bt
#0 tcache_bin_flush_impl (small=true, nflush=81, ptrs=0x7ffff65fe220, binind=, cache_bin=, tcache=, tsd=0x7ffff65fe270) at src/tcache.c:350
#1 tcache_bin_flush_bottom (small=true, rem=0, binind=82, cache_bin=0x7ffff77945b8 <je_arenas+1976>, tcache=0x7ffff7793e00 <je_arenas>, tsd=0x7ffff65fe270) at src/tcache.c:519
#2 je_tcache_bin_flush_small (tsd=tsd@entry=0x7ffff65fecb8, tcache=tcache@entry=0x7ffff65ff010, cache_bin=cache_bin@entry=0x7ffff65ff018, binind=binind@entry=0, rem=rem@entry=0) at src/tcache.c:529
#3 0x00007ffff75764b4 in tcache_flush_cache (tcache=0x7ffff65ff010, tsd=0x7ffff65fecb8) at src/tcache.c:790
#4 tcache_destroy (tsd=tsd@entry=0x7ffff65fecb8, tcache=tcache@entry=0x7ffff65ff010, tsd_tcache=true) at src/tcache.c:809
#5 0x00007ffff7576c31 in je_tcache_cleanup (tsd=tsd@entry=0x7ffff65fecb8) at src/tcache.c:852
#6 0x00007ffff7579039 in tsd_do_data_cleanup (tsd=0x7ffff65fecb8) at src/tsd.c:382
#7 je_tsd_cleanup (arg=0x7ffff65fecb8) at src/tsd.c:408
#8 0x00007ffff79a4408 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd () at pthread_create.c:300
#9 0x00007ffff79a581b in __nptl_deallocate_tsd () at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:200
#10 start_thread (arg=0x7ffff65ff700) at pthread_create.c:473
#11 0x00007ffff721061f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

I have tried re-compiled jemalloc without jemalloc-prefix and use Function (malloc, calloc, realloc, free) directly. it works. It is confusing
